# how does memcached improve on database-level caching?

Tags: database, performance, memcached

I'm a newcomer to `memcached`, but fairly familiar with database internals and systems programming, so this seemed odd to me. It's obvious that a memory-based solution is faster than a disk-based solution, but since any database backing the cache will know more about the structure of data, shouldn't it have a better idea of how to cache it effectively?

I see three possibilities:

1. "Machines deployed with `memcached` have more RAM than database servers typically do." Would adding the same amount of memory make the solutions perform similarly?
2. "Ensuring ACID transactional properties in the database make this speedup difficult to match." Is it possible to get similar-scale speedups by relaxing the transactional guarantees of your database to match those of the cache?
3. "Distributing the database queries across multiple cache machines equally is what allows the speedup." Would sharding the database do the same thing?

If it's not a combination of these, what more does adding a caching layer bring to the table which databases cannot, and why don't/can't database vendors implement a better caching layer themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successful use of memcached isn't about "database-level caching."  That's almost never a good idea.

Instead, you think about all the things you're going to get from the DB to build a "thing" and you cache that thing so you don't have to do it next time.

Also, you can cache lots of things that aren't database.  Anything that's expensive in your app to build or retrieve.  Cache that.

If a DB query is sufficiently fast, don't cache that.